# xml parsing in C# .net Core

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, .net-core

It seem the `System.Xml` is not available in .net core (unit test)

I found a nu get package called DocumentFormat.OpenXml but couldn't find code examples on how to use one.

My requirement is simple to be able to parse a single element like this. Any suggestions.

```
"<message Att='Hello'/>"
```

Comment: Use http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net to locate the correct NuGet packages. Both System.Xml and Linq to XML are available.

Comment: thanks, I'm looking up, what Linq is for?

Comment: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/linq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a comment for using Linq and recommend going that route. That said, I personally haven't tried it in .NET Core.

Try something like...

```
var value = "<message Att='Hello'/>";
var xml = XDocument.Parse(value);
```